# Series about a Teen girl goes to dragon themed summer camp after lifelong obsession with dragons, finds out she's a descendant of dragon slayers

Tags: story-identification

It follows a young rich white girl in her teenage years, I believe her father is a senator. She has had a lifelong obsession with dragons for no reason. She goes to a dragon-themed summer camp, only to find out that her ancestor was a part of an order of knights that hunt dragons. The knights drank this gold elixir that gave them the ability to hear and see out of the eyes and ears of dragons, fly, and use fire, but after generations of gene dilution their descendants can only use one of these powers now.

She gets caught in a love triangle between the boy who can see out of the eyes of a dragon, and the boy who can fly. There was also a group of people that raised and could control dragons, who were at war with the slayers for killing the dragons. One of the descendants of these flew a plane with dragon eggs over DC, which awoke the powers of the knights in the unborn fetuses of 5-7 pregnant women.

Answer (score 11):

[Slayers](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/10579099-slayers) by C.J. Hill.

[image]

> Dragons exist. They're ferocious. And they're smart: Before they were killed off by slayer-knights, they rendered a select group of eggs dormant, so their offspring would survive. Only a handful of people know about this, let alone believe it – these "Slayers" are descended from the original knights, and are now a diverse group of teens that includes Tori, a smart but spoiled senator's daughter who didn't sign up to save the world.
>
> The dragon eggs have fallen into the wrong hands. The Slayers must work together to stop the eggs from hatching. They will fight; they will fall in love. But will they survive?

The origin of the Slayers is described in the book as:

> “Let me explain some more,” Alastair said soothingly. “Do you remember that back in the Middle Ages, how the alchemists tried to find a way to create gold? History got that wrong. They sought to create liquid gold—a substance that would give people the powers needed to conquer dragons. Luckily, they were able to create it. Those super enhanced knights would’ve destroyed dragons altogether if some of the dragons hadn’t used their long gestation periods to outlive them.”
>
> Allen wiped his palms on his jeans. “You know how to make this liquid gold stuff?”
>
> Alastair realized he hadn’t explained that part. “I don’t need to. Once the knights drank the liquid gold, it changed their DNA. They passed that DNA down to future generations. When a dragon is close to hatching, it emits a pulse, and that pulse turns on the DNA of any of the dragon knights’ descendants who are within a mile radius.” He put his hand on top of Harriet’s arm. “You had the dream because you’re a descendant of a dragon knight. At some point, you went near a dragon egg in the D.C. area.”
>
> She yanked her arm away and let out a half-strangled gasp. “That’s why the dragon was searching for me? It knew I was a descendant?”
>
> “Yes.”
>
> She stood up so quickly her blanket fell away, and her chair toppled to the floor with a sharp crack. She didn’t bother to right it. “I’m not fighting that thing. I don’t have any special powers.”
>
> “You don’t,” Alastair agreed. “But your son does. The pulse can only turn on the DNA of babies.” He gestured to her stomach. “Those who are still in the womb.”